# When writing in English (or other Latin script languages), which is correct (or preferred): TeX or ΤεΧ?

Tags: tex-core

Using FontForge, I was interested to see that they spell TeX with Greek letters
(ΤεΧ), as seen below:

[image: ΤεΧ General]

I had always up to now seen it written out in Latin lettering, but is the style used by FontForge actually right, and I'm wrong?

Comment: Isn't `\varepsilon` lower case? `\TeX` is actually TEX, all upper case, and as far as I know the greep upper case of tau epsilon chi are the latin TEX.

Comment: I have been using TeX for over 35 years and I don't think I've ever seen it written like that

Comment: Citing _the_ authoritative reference on TeX: “The correct way to refer to \TeX\ in a computer file, or when using some other medium that doesn't allow lowering of the \`E', is to type \`TeX'.”

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Your citation is obviously correct, presumably that was written when one could not easily type a Greek letter in a computer file?

Comment: @luaplaying I have no idea.  I for one don't know how to type ε other than with copy-pasting or changing the keyboard layout to greek.  On the other hand, Don says on the TeXbook: “For example, the author developed TEX on a keyboard that includes the symbols ← , ↓ , ≠ , ≤ , and ≥”.  It doesn't look like keyboards were less capable back then than they are today.  What could be a limitation was the ability of the _software_ back then (since it was mostly English-centric) to represent characters other than ASCII